# Protractor:Assertion on arrayofelements.getText() is returning empty list

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Below assertion code is not working in CI(due to slowness,maybe) but works perfectly fine in my local system
In CI,I dont get the list of elements at all or it returns just one or two elements in array of actual elements

```
var expectedFromLevels = ['Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4'];
var expectedToLevels= ['Level 3', 'Level 4','Level 5'];
expect(dashboard.getAllFromLevels()).toEqual(expectedFromLevels)
expect(dashboard.getAllToLevels()).toEqual(expectedToLevels)//this has to be called only after getAllFromLevels is assertion is complete

//definition of getAllFromLevels()
    getAllFromLevels : {
        value: function () {
          return element.all(by.css('#from-levels .nlq-sel--level')).getText();
      }
    //definition of getAllToLevels()
    getAllToLevels : {
        value: function() {
          return element.all(by.css('#to-levels .nlq-sel--level')).getText();
          };

**Results::**
In my local system: passed

**In CI:::**
Expected [ 'Level 2', 'Level 3' ] to equal [ 'Level 2', 'Level 3', 'Level 4' ].
Expected [ 'Level 3', '' ] to equal [ 'Level 3', 'Level 4', 'Level 5' ].
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in CI by adding browser wait statements-I know this is not ideal way of doing but this is workaround that works for time being-

```
    getAllLevelsCount : {
    value: function (elements, n) {
  return function () {
    return elements.count(function (count) {
      return count >= n;
    });
  };
}
browser.wait(dashboard.getAllLevelsCount($$("cssid"), 3) , 10000);
```